# SQL - how to select where column contains string separated by space

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL column "attributes" where is value:

```
11235 11236 11237 11238 11239 11240
```

In other rows (same column) is value:

```
233 234 235 236 237
```

I need make `SELECT` where column contains "235". I can't use `WHERE LIKE "%235%"` because that code select `11235` and I need only where is `235` separated by space.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you store data like that? Separate rows for each value is so much better, and use int data type!

Comment: If you want to use SQL, normalize your data. If you don't want to normalize your data, don't use SQL for this. Other tools would be better to suited to that task.

Comment: I have normalized this numbers in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend not storing data like this -- much easier to query if it were normalized.

However, here's one option using `concat`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where concat(' ', field, ' ') like '% 235 %';
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bad db schema, and you should think about normalization. Here is one way to deal with this situation using `find_in_set`

```
mysql> select find_in_set('11235',replace('11235 11236 11237 11238 11239 11240',' ',',')) val;
+-----+
| val |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you may use as

```
select * from table_name where 
find_in_set('235',replace(col_name,' ',',')) > 0
```